SwiftData inserts duplicate item to one-to-many relationship with #Preview
I have a simple logic that adds an item to an one-to-many relationship.
        let modelA = ModelA.createDummyData()
        modelContext.insert(modelA)
        
        // simply create ModelB() then modelB.modelA = modelA
        let modelB = ModelB.createDummyData(for: modelA)
        
        print(modelA.modelBs.count) // HERE = 1

        do {
            try modelContext.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("[ERROR] \(error)")
        }
        
        let t = try! modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<ModelA>()).first!
        print(t.modelBs.count) // HERE = 2 !!!

You see, just after a save, the number of modelBs duplicated. These duplicates are unique items, verified with UUID()s (which I did not create). Also I was comparing the same modelAs before and after save. Also verified by its id = UUID().
Definition of relationship follows best practice and examples, only adding @Relationship to one side.
@Model public class ModelA {
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \ModelB.modelA) public var modelB: [ModelB] = []
}

@Model public class ModelB {
    public var modelA: ModelA?
}

I tried to use SQL debug but don't really find the generated SQLs useful. I also logged from the ModelB init() function and found only 1 call made.
Why is this happening? How do I debug?

What is createDummyData?

@vadian Just sth like let b = ModelB(); b.modelA = modelA;. There is nothing between printing the count, and save(), and printing again.

Now I have tried your code and this is not reproducible. Not surprisingly really since the code (the one posted as least) is pretty straightforward. Either you are doing something in your functions or init methods that are incorrect or the fetch is returning some other object than the one you created.

For anyone who encountered this issue, here are my findings.

This almost exclusively occurs with #Preview, very very rarely happens on Simulator runs (only once or twice and hard to reproduce)
So far this only happens for in-memory stores
I could occasionally get the .fetch() to return correct ModelB count but when passed in a View, in .onAppear the count is doubled again; I've even seen cases with tripled counts!
Adding .unique constraints on id field did not help
MY SOLUTION: Since this is only for previewing and debugging, I added a manual reset using ModelContext.delete(model:) before insertion, now the count is correct

Sometimes the code in #Preview would run twice after changing the code, I thought that in-memory store may not get reset between those runs, but even if that was the case I should have got 2 ModelAs each with 1 ModelB, not 1 ModelAs with 2 ModelBs.
I suspect this is a bug in in-memory stores of SwiftData (or how it interplays with the Preview mechanism) because my old Core Data had a similar in-memory store for previewing but I'd never seen anything like this. I've been migrating Core Data code to SwiftData and this has puzzled me for quite a while.

Maybe you could have mentioned in the question that this was a preview issue.

@JoakimDanielson I mostly develop with preview so only noticed that after exhausting other ways to locate the issue. I edited the title, sorry for the confusion.
